# Multiple Dates as Columns - Groupby

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I have this simple data frame

```
province  |country | 1/2 | 1/3
   A_1    |   A    | 444 | 444
   A_2    |   A    |  26 |  32
   B_1    |   B    |  1  |  1
```

I'm able to successfully run the following:

```
df_1 = df.groupby(['country'],as_index=False)['1/2', '1/3'].sum()
df_1
```

Which returns a dataframe df_1 as:

```
 country | 1/2 | 1/3
    A    | 470 | 476
    B    |  1  |  1
```

My question is, what if I had dates for an entire month? Is there an easier way than explicitly writing every single date in the code above?
Something like

```
 df_1 = df.groupby(['country'],as_index=False)[df.iloc[:,2:]].sum()
```

But this returns a "'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed" error.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to columns iterable - `df.columns`:

```py
df_1 = df.groupby(['country'],as_index=False)[df.columns[2:]].sum()
```

Comment: Thank you!! Works perfectly.

Comment: What if their is daily columns in multiple months and we want to group by months?